# Previous screen called when navigating to new one in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the exact same problem as described [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6870). When navigating between screens using Tabs or a drawer, each screen is reloaded, causing issues with my app.

I have tried to follow some of the recommendations given in the thread, but I can't apply it with my code. E.g.:

> For me the solution was to nest the navigators as child of the screen component and not inserting the navigator into the component property.

> Wrap it in the top level of the file and assign it to a variable, then use that variable inside your component.

My drawer is composed of 4 shortcuts to 4 screens (Home, History, Groups, Settings). The first three are also available from the Home screen in bottom-tabs.

Here is my code:
`Navigation.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import { Entypo } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import Settings from "../screens/Settings";
import Loading from "../screens/Loading";
import AddGroup from "../screens/AddGroup";
import GroupList from "../screens/GroupList";

import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Groups from "../screens/Groups";
import History from "../screens/History";

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
const HomeStackScreen = ({ route }) => (
  <HomeStack.Navigator}>
    <HomeStack.Screen
      name={route.name}
      component={Home}
    />
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
);

const HistoryStack = createStackNavigator();
const HistoryStackScreen = ({ route }) => (
  <HistoryStack.Navigator>
    <HistoryStack.Screen
      name={route.name}
      component={History}
    />
  </HistoryStack.Navigator>
);

const GroupsStack = createStackNavigator();
const GroupsStackScreen = ({ route }) => (
  <GroupsStack.Navigator>
    <GroupsStack.Screen
      name={route.name}
      component={Groups}
    />
  </GroupsStack.Navigator>
);

const AppTabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
const bottomTabsScreen = ({ route }) => (
  <AppTabs.Navigator>
    <AppTabs.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeStackScreen}
    />
    <AppTabs.Screen
      name="History"
      component={HistoryStackScreen}
    />

    <AppTabs.Screen
      name="Groups"
      component={GroupsStackScreen}
    />
  </AppTabs.Navigator>
);

const AppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const AppDrawerScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <AppDrawer.Navigator>
    <AppDrawer.Screen name="Home" component={bottomTabsScreen} />

    <AppDrawer.Screen name="History" component={HistoryStackScreen} />

    <AppDrawer.Screen name="Groups" component={GroupsStackScreen} />

    <AppDrawer.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
  </AppDrawer.Navigator>
);

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();
const RootStackScreen = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(!isLoading);
    }, 500);
  }, []);

  return (
    <RootStack.Navigator mode="modal">
      {isLoading ? (
        <RootStack.Screen name="Loading" component={Loading} />
      ) : (
        <RootStack.Screen
          name="AppDrawerScreen"
          component={AppDrawerScreen}
        />
      )}
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="AddGroup"
        component={AddGroup}
        options={modalOptionStyle}
      />

      <RootStack.Screen
        name="GroupList"
        component={GroupList}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerTitle: "Select an existing group",
        })}
      />
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStackScreen />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

`index.js`:

```js
import React from "react";
import Navigation from "./config/Navigation";
import { ConversionContextProvider } from "./util/ConversionContext";

export default () => (
  <ConversionContextProvider>
    <Navigation />
  </ConversionContextProvider>
);
```

Final working code after following x00 recommendations:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (isFocusedGroups) setLoading(true);
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
    loadFlatlist("groups")
      .then()
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  });
  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation, isFocusedGroups]);
```

Comment: Your code has errors in it. For one thing: `modalOptionStyle` is not defined. Probably it don't matter but obscures your issue. Same goes for `navigation` prop in `AppDrawerScreen` you are not actually using. Etc. Plz remove noise and make a *minimal* reproducible example (big chance you'll solve your problem yourself in the process). Also you should show some screens' code and the way you navigate. Also inline function `options={({ navigation }) => ({ headerTitle: "Select an existing group" })}` can cause some rerenders, but probably only for `GroupList`. Anyway, we need more code

Comment: I've created a repro [here](https://snack.expo.io/@javo222/repro_rerender_problem), I will try to clean it up later today with minimum code. When switching between History and Groups tab, you can see in the console **"LOADING FLATLIST (loadFlatlist) FOR: savedRuns"** executed each time. I think that's the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form your repo:

```js
...
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
...
const History = ({ navigation }) => {
  ...
  const isFocusedHistory = useIsFocused();
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    ...
    loadFlatlist("savedRuns")
    ...
  }, [isFocusedHistory]);
  ...
}
```

every time a user opens **or** closes the tab `isFocusedHistory` changes, so the corresponding component re-renders and effects get triggered.

Haven't read the whole app you've wrote and haven't tried to understand what's the desired behavior is, so can't say exactly how you need to change it. But that's the root cause of your issue.

Probably, you should ditch the idea of retrieving the data on the tab switch. That's not a great idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I removed that but the problem is that the data in the tab does not get refreshed when I move tab. Why isn't that a great idea? If a user saves a run, and goes to `History`, then back to `Home` to save another run, I want the second run to be displayed in the flatlist in `History` if the user navigates there (i.e. call `loadFlatlist` again). I was under the impression that `useIsFocused` would help me to do that.

Comment: You can use some kind of store (Redux, MobX, etc), you can pass data as props, or in a context. But if you want to request data on tab switch that will only happen **along** with re-render. `useEffect` wont magically run in the background (unless you'll put `setInterval` in there)

Comment: Well, I still don't know the desired behavior. But you can run `useEffect` only when a tab is shown (and not when it's hidden). For that you can simply put `if(isFocusedHistory)` inside of `useEffect`

Comment: Thanks, I eventually managed to solve it. Added the working sample in my original question